# Ошибка redirect_uri is invalid в OAuth2

Tags: java, vkontakte-api

Пробую создать Standalone-приложение на Java для работы с VKApi.

В документации прочитал, что для получения UserAuthResponse необходимо передать в качестве аргумента redirectUri следующую ссылку: `https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html`

Но когда я пробую ее передать, возникает ошибка:

> Internal API server error. Wrong status code: 401. Content: {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"redirect_uri is invalid, please pass same redirect_uri, you used in authorize method."}

Вот мой код:

```
TransportClient transportClient = new HttpTransportClient();
        VkApiClient vk = new VkApiClient(transportClient);

        UserAuthResponse authResponse = null;
        try {
            authResponse = vk.oAuth()
                    .userAuthorizationCodeFlow(51484448,
                                               "clientSecret",
                                               "https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html",
                                               "code")
                    .execute();
        } catch (ApiException | ClientException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Вместо clientSecret у меня вставлен код, который я взял со страницы приложения, а code я получил, когда выполнил запрос по типу:
`https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=1&display=page&redirect_uri=http://example.com/callback&scope=friends&response_type=code&v=5.131`

Answer (score 0):

Он у вас ругается, что `redirect_uri` первого запроса (где вы получали `code`) и второго запроса (уже в коде) отличается. Для правильной работы, code нужно получать по ссылке такого вида: `https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=51484448&display=page&redirect_uri=https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html&scope=friends&response_type=code&v=5.131`. Таким образом всё должно заработать.